# Aspose.Cells - The File is Corrupted

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

When I try to open a text file to a xlsx format from Aspose.Cells with this code:

```
Excel.Workbook workbook = new Excel.Workbook(filePath, new Excel.TxtLoadOptions(Excel.LoadFormat.Xlsx) { SeparatorString = " " });
```

it crashes with the exception being **The file is corrupted**. This is only happening since yesterday.

I feel like nothing changed that could possibly affect the Aspose.Cells library from functionning correctly.

I have searched quite a bit online, but nothing really relates to a file being corrupted when opening it.

I thought at first that the text files were the issue, but I tried creating a new text file with the text: **"test test1 test2"**

Even with this new file it is still telling me it is corrupted.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**: After further review and testing, by removing the parameter **new Excel.TxtLoadOptions(Excel.LoadFormat.Xlsx) { SeparatorString = " " }**

It works, but the text only gets put into one cell instead of splitting it between multiple cells. Any ideas of a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Well, a file containing random text is not a file in the Excel format, especially not Xlsx which is a particular zipped file. Why would you expect this to work?

Comment: Because it did. This loads a text file into a xlsx format. The content of the file does not matter.

Comment: What happens when you split your text with commas instead of spaces and remove the portion `{ SeparatorString = " " }`

Comment: Then why do you pass `Excel.LoadFormat.Xlsx`? You're not loading an XSLX file.

Comment: It is txtLoadOptions object. You are passing the file type you want to load the text file to. @CodeCaster

Comment: I will try asap @Dumisani

Comment: It still does the same when separated with commas and removing the property SeparatorString. @Dumisani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

In my case I was loading the text file into a .xlsx extension due to me wanting to save the file back to xlsx after applying formatting.

Turns out that the Aspose.cells API is not able to load a .txt as xlsx. However, you can load it as a CSV than save it as an xlsx after like so:

```
Excel.Workbook workbook = new Excel.Workbook(filePath, new Excel.TxtLoadOptions(Excel.LoadFormat.CSV) { SeparatorString = " " });
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.